# Intune powershell script

Tags: powershell, automation, intune

I cant for the life of me figure out how to save the current PowerShell script to a specific location on a client so I can create a scheduled task to execute it on log on. The script is being run from intune. So after it runs I need to save it to Program data and be able to call it.

something along the lines of copy "`$PSCommandPath:" to c:\programdata\script

`if ($PSCommandPath -eq $null) { function GetPSCommandPath() { return $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath; } $PSCommandPath = GetPSCommandPath; }`

```
function PSCommandPath() { return $PSCommandPath; }
function ScriptName() { return $MyInvocation.ScriptName; }
function MyCommandName() { return $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name; }
function MyCommandDefinition() {
# Begin of MyCommandDefinition()
# Note: ouput of this script shows the contents of this function, not the 
       execution result
return $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
# End of MyCommandDefinition()
      }
 function MyInvocationPSCommandPath() { return 
  $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath; }
 Write-Host "`$PSCommandPath:";
 Write-Host " *   Direct: $PSCommandPath";
 Write-Host " * Function: $(PSCommandPath)";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, for me it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Thank you though

Comment: Then please either delete the question or create your own answer.